# How can I print the ip with the following code in html with js?

Tags: html

The code I have does work with onclick events but I want to print it in the footer or somewhere

```
 async function getIP() {
     try {
         const res = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
         const jsonObj = (res.json()).then(data => alert(data.ip));
     } catch (err) {
         console.error(err);
     }
 }
```

I did `<div id="iptext" class="ip"></div>`
and then getIdbyElement but it didn't work

also when I did document.write which I don't like then I can't implement it in my html it only comes up with a white screen so.
the 2nd problem is that I can't just move the text without my text without having any text here.

Comment: Please include some of the "I have tried stuff like..." attempts, your description sounds like it should work but we can't help correct it without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
async function getIP() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
    const jsonObj = await res.json();
    document.getElementById('iptext').textContent = jsonObj.ip;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

getIP();
```

```html
<span id="iptext"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have `<div id="iptext" class="ip"></div>` then you can get this element like `document.querySelector('.ip')` or `document.querySelector('#iptext')`.

You can put the text into it like `document.querySelector('#iptext').innerHTML(res)`